# Cumulative numbers in python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to add numbers in a dictionary, cumulative so it will add the keys of the dictionary.

```
x = ' '
dict = {}
list = []
while x != '':
x = raw_input('Enter line:')
p = x.split(' ')
if x != '':
    list.append(p)
result = sum(list, [])
result = result
num = []
for a in result:
for n in dict:
    p = a.count(a)
    l = a
    if n == l:
        l += l
dict[a] = p
print dict

raw_input('')
```

I would like "dict" to consist of the words from the input and the amount of times that they were entered.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
x=raw_input('enter line\n')
if x.strip():
    x=x.split()
    count=Counter(x)
    dic=dict(count)
    print dic
else:
    print 'you entered nothing'
```

**output:**

```
>>> 
enter line
cat cat spam eggs foo foo bar bar bar foo
{'eggs': 1, 'foo': 3, 'bar': 3, 'cat': 2, 'spam': 1}
```

and without using `Counter`(which is not recommended) you can use `sets`:

```
dic= {}
x = raw_input('Enter line:')
if x.strip():
    p = x.split()
    for x in set(p):   #set(p) contains only unique elements of p
        dic[x]=p.count(x)
    print dic
else:
    print 'you entered nothing'
```

**output:**

```
>>> 
Enter line: cat cat spam eggs foo foo bar bar bar foo
{'eggs': 1, 'foo': 3, 'bar': 3, 'cat': 2, 'spam': 1}
```

Comment: I've tryed all of that, trying to put it into the code and got this:

    from collections import Counter

    x = ' '
    dict = {}
    list = []
    x = raw_input('Enter Line:')
    while x != '':
        p = x.split(' ')
        if x != '':
            list.append(p)
        result = sum(list, [])
        result = result
        count = Counter(result)
        dict[result] = count
        x = raw_input('Enter line:')

Comment: @AngusMoore don't post code in comments, It's almost unreadable.

Comment: I wasnt sure where else, to respond to him

Comment: @AngusMoore many parts of the code you've posted in question are redundant, I've added the `if` condition to my answers.

Comment: @AngusMoore just add the code you posted in comments to the bottom of the question.

Comment: When I do it with very large input, I get a NameError on line the `for x in set(p)`, I am using the one with out Counter, because `dic=dict(count)` wasn't working, I did `from collections import Counter` as well. Any ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15220/discussion-between-ashwini-chaudhary-and-angus-moore)

Comment: @AngusMoore `dict(count)` is not working coz you've declared a variable named `dict `in your code, see I just used `dic` and also using `list` as a variable name is no good.

What's the `NameError` you're getting?

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.7 has [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which can be used to give you a running total of words.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

lines = iter(lambda: raw_input('Enter line:'), '') # read until empty line
print Counter(word for line in lines for word in line.split()).most_common()
```